# Exporting wp site as a theme

Tags: theme-development

I have build a simple theme using "underscore". How do I duplicate/export it as a zip file so that I can upload it through"**Appearance => themes => Add New**"

Please note that I don't want a backup of site or duplicating the site. I need it to be used as a theme so I can distribute it as a "Free Theme"

UPDATE: I zipped the whole theme folder and upload it. Now the problem is that plugins won't move.

Comment: to find informations about creating theme, look in the codex : https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: Thanks. That document explain how to build a theme, doesn't  say how to export it as a theme. I already know how to build it with _underscores.

Comment: You want to do something else/more than just zipping a folder?

Comment: Is just zipping the folder enough? Would it be upload-able as a theme through "Appearance" menu? I'll test it.

Comment: What do you mean by "plugins won't move"? Plugins and their settings are not part of a theme.

Comment: So for example if I want the theme to have a "slider", do I need to write the code and I cannot use a plug in like mega slider?